# How to work with Action<IBoundClient> expressions like a IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

I have a service, that is communicating via OData with other Services.  The project is using the nuget Simple.OData.Client [here](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client) and the company has
provided an interface for the communication with a function, that I **have** to use.

the function looks like this:

```
        private async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FetchEntitiesAsync<T>(string prefix, Action<IBoundClient<T>> configure,
            CancellationToken token) where T : class
        {
            IBoundClient<T> query = _client.For<T>(prefix);
            configure(query);

            try
            {
                this.Logger.LogDebug($"Fetching {_baseUri}/{prefix} via OData...");

                IEnumerable<T> entities = await query.FindEntriesAsync(token);
                return entities;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.Logger.LogError(e, $"{prefix} acquisition OData exception");
                this.Logger.LogError(e.StackTrace);

                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Now I have to provide a Action<IBoundClient>. Actually I can't figure out how to really work with this.

I can do something like this:

```
Action<IBoundClient<MyClass>> filter = (q => q.Filter(i => i.Property1 == myProperty1).Expand(i => i.MyParameters));

FetchEntityAsync("MyClass", filter, token);
```

But for some cases i need to put more logic into the filter object. Than i came up with a solution like

```
Action<IBoundClient<MyClass>> filter;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property2))
   {

     filter = (q => q.Filter(i => i.Property1 == myProperty1)
            .Expand(i => i.Columns));
   }
   else
   {
      filter = (q => q.Filter(i => i.Property1 == myProperty2)
             .Filter(i => i.Property2.ToLower() == property2.ToLower())
             .Expand(i => i.Columns));
   }

   FetchEntityAsync("MyClass", filter, token);
```

This will become very messy with increased complexity
I want to do something similar to EntityFramework where I can work with a Queryable like

```
myQuery = myQuery.Where(x=> x.Property1 = myProperty1);

if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(property2){
  myQuery = myQueryable.Where(x=> x.Property2.toLower() = property2.toLower());
}

[...]
```

Comment: From what I see, `IQueryable` is nowhere near the API this library offers (which you better mention in the question, BTW). What you ask is a query provider that translates LINQ statements into their fluent API.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your comment. I was thinking, that the IBoundClient was provided by Microsoft. But the company is using  a nuget Package that I've found https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client